# Send webRTC getUserMedia webCam stream over socketio

Tags: node.js, socket.io, webrtc, getusermedia

I have this piece of code:

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(param)
.then(function(stream) {
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.play();
  }
})
.catch(function (err) {});
```

In this code I want to send this stream over socketio to nodejs server so that I can use it on receiver end for display in video element.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this is your best bet: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17938723/5915143

You'd record the stream using MediaStreamRecorder and send it with 'emit()' calls on socket io to your server.

Alternatively you can use a streaming library built on socket.io like Endpoint.js to handle the stream.

Comment: Could you please look into this comment

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/#comment-4236508895

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53731348/how-to-send-and-receive-desktop-capture-stream-generated-via-getusermedia